# On('change') not triggering

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically Generating input fields of the type file. but when i try to get its triggered event nothing happens.

below is the dynamic input file

```
<div id="documentlist" class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="input-group">        
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-exists" data-provides="fileinput">
      <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file m-r-10 waves-effect">
        <span class="fileinput-new">Upload Your </span>
        <span class="fileinput-exists">Document</span>
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="">
        <input id="0" class="selectdocument" type="file" name="..." multiple>
      </span>
      <span id="form_f" class="fileinput-filename"></span>
      <a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">×</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my event handler

```
 // Select Document Form 
    $('#documentlist').on('change', '.selectdocument', function () {
        alert(this.id);
    });
```

Comment: Please, avoid horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: You have to bind change to the input not to some parent element.

Comment: Also using id="0" is asking for trouble. Try to use something more specific because all IDs in the document must be unique.

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '.selectdocument', function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});`

Comment: Zakaria Acharki its not a duplicate of what you have marked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `change` for `select` element and `input` for `input` elements.

```
$('#documentlist').on('input', '.selectdocument', function () {
    alert($(this).closest('.col-lg-12').attr('id'));
});
```